# BSOD when installing AMD graphics drivers

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bsod, amd-catalyst, amd-graphics-card

This problem is a recurring one. I've had it happen before, but I've always been able to fix it. Whenever I try to install Windows drivers for my MSI R6570 graphics card, I get a blue screen with something along the lines of "faulty drivers." Before, it was simply a matter of installing the chipset and integrated graphics drivers before attempting to install the new drivers. However, this time they were already installed and verified to be working.

Here's a link to a set of relevant data (including all of the steps of the process, the BSOD, and some potentially useful system files):

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2tLzzy_FsHsflZPOU9XWHdZNzRVcE1mV3pzYThrYXNINi1zaWRPTDJtQVIzdWtWMzVVenM&usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

You get the [bugcheck 0xCA - PNP_DETECTED_FATAL_ERROR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560209%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
PNP_DETECTED_FATAL_ERROR (ca)
PnP encountered a severe error, either as a result of a problem in a driver or
a problem in PnP itself.  The first argument describes the nature of the
problem, the second argument is the address of the PDO.  The other arguments
vary depending on argument 1.
Arguments:
Arg1: 000000000000000b, Deleted PDO reported as relation
    One of the removal relations for the device being removed has
    already been deleted.
```

You still use the Windows 7 RTM from 2009 without any updates.

```
Windows 7 Kernel Version 7600 MP (2 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 7600.16385.amd64fre.win7_rtm.090713-1255
```

First install the Sp1 + all updates and now try to install the AMD catalyst driver.

Comment: I installed all of the updates and SP1 as well, but I still get the same error. Are there any other required programs/libraries I may need?

Comment: which driver version do you try to install? try different drivers.

Comment: I tried installing the latest Catalyst suite from the AMD website, which is 14.12 Omega, and I also tried the CD from MSI which included Catalyst 9.2 (I think). Both of them result in the same error.

Comment: try the 13.12 or an other older driver: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/previous?os=Windows%208.1%20-%2064

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening for a variety of reasons.

1. Drivers - you mentioned this so I'll put it first, but make sure all the necessary system drivers are installed properly.
2. Faulty equipment - Your GPU, Mobo, RAM, HDD, all can produce BSOD messages.  Since you mentioned you've got it working before this probably isn't the problem.  But in my experience most BSOD errors are actually caused by faulty hardware.
3. Insufficient Power - If the card or other computer components aren't receiving enough electricity they will often BSOD.  I'd make sure you have enough power throughout the system.

Comment: These are all good points; however I am certain it is not a hardware error. The BSOD message indicated it was a driver/software error. To support this fact, I've been using this setup for a couple of years and it's worked with no problems. I'm currently running Ubuntu on another hard disk with proprietary graphics drivers and absolutely no issues.